# Does Grails support Hibernate Optimistic Lock Type ALL?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.5

Grails domain class annotated with:

```
@OptimisticLocking(type = OptimisticLockType.ALL)
@DynamicUpdate
class T...
```

When calling save on the domain object, the generated SQL update statement only includes id columns in the where clause, not all columns. Does Grails (version 2.5.1) support all the Hibernate annotations including OptimisticLockType.ALL?

Comment: "When calling save on the domain class, the generated SQL update statement only includes id columns in the where clause, not all columns." - Why would any column other than the id be included in the where clause when saving an instance?

Comment: In Hibernate there are four OptimisticLockTypes: NONE, VERSION, ALL, DIRTY. Default is VERSION, in which the update statement includes the @Version column in the where. ALL "performs optimistic locking based on all fields as part of an expanded WHERE clause restriction for the UPDATE/DELETE SQL statements". (See the Versionless optimistic locking section in https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/locking/Locking.html)

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks.